# Python's win10toast module not working as intended

Tags: python, module, notifications

I have been using python's win10toast module to create desktop notifications as part of my project.

However recently it is not working properly.

When I run the following code:

```
    import win10toast
    toast = win10toast.ToastNotifier()
    toast.show_toast("Python","Hello World",duration=10)
```

The python icon appears in the taskbar but no notification comes up in the tray.
I have tried reinstalling the module and increasing the duration to as long as 100 seconds. Still no avail.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when using plyer. Here's my solution:

Click the Action center icon in the bottom right corner. Click the 'Manage Notifications' text in the top right corner of the window. This will take you to a settings page. Here, make sure the 'Get Notifications from other apps and other senders' is turned on.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem after a windows update.
The problem is that python doesn't show up in the list 'Get notifications from these senders' in 'notification and actions settings'.

Steps that solved it:

1. Run:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("title",'content', threaded=False, icon_path=None, duration=60)
```

2. Quicky open 'Notifications and actions settings'. The list under 'Get notifications from these senders' will refresh and include 'Python'.
3. Now you can unsilence the notification.

If this doens't solve it, plyer is a great alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of quiet hours in windows 10 action center.

At the bottom right corner, click the Action Center icon. Disable "Quiet Hours" setting if turned on. After You disable "Quiet Hours", toast notifications can appear.

Comment: Nope. It's turned off and the notifications are not coming. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the issue was with only win10toast. So I switched to plyer and then there was no problem.